# error al usar el comando git push -u origin -all en windows

Tags: git, git-push, bitbucket

Estoy enlazando mi primera aplicación de *Ruby* en *Windows* con un repositorio remoto, pero me quedo en este punto:

Primero adiciono el origen y funciona bien:

```
C:\Sites\hello_app>git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:lurisnel/hello_app.git
```

Pero luego al hacer `push` me sale siempre el mismo error:

```
C:\Sites\hello_app>git push -u origin --all
To git@bitbucket.org:lurisnel/hello_app.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:lurisnel/hello_app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Ya creé una cuenta en *bitbucket* y tengo un repositorio llamado *hello_app*.

**Agradzco de antemano su ayuda.**

Comment: Tienes `commit` pendientes por subir?

Comment: ¿Actualizaste algo en tu repositorio remoto (por ejemplo el _readme_) después de crearlo?

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que el repositorio remoto tiene cambios que aún no has reflejado en tu repositorio local.

Confirma que tu repositorio sea el correcto y, en caso que así sea, actualiza tu repositorio local con esos cambios:

Primero baja el código:

```
git fetch origin
```

Verifica los cambios que se hicieron (para asegurarte que no harán daño en tu código actual).

Una vez que confirmes, actualiza tu repositorio:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Al terminar el `merge` (resolviendo conflictos en caso que existan) podrás hacer el `push` sin problema.